HM encoder , error in running commands
I am new to HM and I am encountering the same issue , which I cant run any command if I am not in its directory (exp: to run encoder_intra_main.cfg I must be in the cfg directory )
I know its from the path but what should I do in order to have access on everything in the HM (main directory) so that I can run any command
